# UIImage View in TableView Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiimage

im doing tableview controller with images and i used this code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    var program : Program

    program = programy[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = program.name
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    var imageName = UIImage(named: programy[indexPath.row])
    cell.imageView?.image = imageName
```

and im getting error in

var imageName = UIImage(named: programy[indexPath.row])

Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type (named $T5)

Comment: `UIImage(named:String)` expects a String. How is your array `programy` defined?

Comment: var programy = [Program]() and 
struct Program {
    let category : String
    let name : String
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already get the name of the image from your array in the code above, so you might want to use it for the UIImage inintalization, too:

```
var imageName = UIImage(named: program.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can see that `programy` contains `Program` types. `UIImage(named: String)` expects a `String` so you need to give that `Program.name` or `Program.category`. Try this

```
var imageName = UIImage(named: program.name)
```